# Необходим алгоритм разбиения натурального числа n на m частей (нули тоже входят) или хотя бы набросок?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Есть алгоритм, но он не понятен и не доходчив:

Генерация композиций натурального числа n по заданному рангу m означает: всевозможными способами разбить n на m целых неотрицательных слагаемых.
Другими словами, разбить всевозможными способами n записанных подряд единиц на заданное число m частей (допускаются и пустые части).
Если в качестве символов-разделителей выбрать нули, то m частей порождаются m-1 разделителями, т.е. m-1 нулями. Таким образом, задача сводится к перебору битовых строк длины q=n+m-1, отсеивая те, в которых число нулей отлично от m-1.

В качестве вспомогательного алгоритма нам понадобится алгоритм порождения всех двоичных последовательностей длины q.
Используется битовый массив b[q], b[q-1], ..., b[0], который вначале обнуляется.
Для записи порожденной последовательности служат b[q-1], ..., b[0], b[q] – только для технических целей: порождающий цикл завершается, как только b[q] станет равно 1.
while b[q]=0 do
begin
1. вывод последовательности b[q-1], ..., b[0];
2. найти первый справа налево нулевой элемент b[i] и заменить его на единицу, а все элементы правее него стереть до нуля.
end

Comment: Кнут, "Искусство программирования", том 4а, раздел 7.2.1.4, алгоритм H - разбиение числа n на m частей. Правда, они все ненулевые, но вам достаточно применить его для всех i от 1 до m, добавляя нужное количество нулей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ограничений на величину слагаемых нет, то количество разбиений равно C<sup>m-1</sup><sub>n-1</sub>. И получается очевидным образом именно из предложенного вам подхода: "разбить всевозможными способами n записанных подряд единиц на заданное число m частей". Это [метод шаров и перегородок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Генерацию разбивающих последовательностей организовать несложно. [Известный "побитовый" хак](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications) выглядит вот так (на С или С++)

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned u = x & -x;
  unsigned v = u + x;
  x = v  + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
  return x;
}
```

и позволяет вам генерировать все битовые наборы с фиксированным количеством единичных битов в рамках поддерживаемого языком целого типа.

"Нехаковый" алгоритм проще описать без "битовых наборов". Простой алгоритм представляет собой генерацию последовательных `m`-значных чисел в специальной системе счисления: цифры этой системы лежат в диапазоне `[1, n)` и в каждом числе всегда идут строго по возрастанию. (Это ни что иное, как [*комбинаторная система счисления*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), хотя в каноническом определении цифры обычно убывают.) Каждая цифра - это позиция разделителя между шарами.

Например, для `n = 6` и `m = 3` генерируем `123`, `124`, `125`, `134`, `135`, `145`, `234`, `235`, ..., `345`. Логика *последовательной* генерации таких чисел тривиальна

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10u
#define M 3u

int main(void) {
  unsigned digits[M];
  unsigned i;

  for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    digits[i] = i + 1;

  do {
    unsigned overflow;

    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
      printf("[%u]", digits[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = M - 1, overflow = N; i != -1; --i, --overflow)
      if (++digits[i] < overflow)
        break;

    if (i == -1)
      break;

    for (++i; i < M; ++i)
      digits[i] = digits[i - 1] + 1;

  } while (1);
}
```